# Filter by DENSE_RANK

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, dense-rank

Asked  a questions very similar to this, and got a working answer, but I had to modify my code to include more variables, and the solution doesn't quite work any more

I've been filtering out bad data from a large set of SF bus time schedules - I have most of it sorted, but I'm getting lines that have duplicated data. My query looks like this:

```
WITH ad AS (SELECT  
    route_id, 
    trip_id, 
    direction,
    trip_date, 
    stop_name,
    aimed_arrival_time,
    DENSE_RANK() OVER(partition by trip_id, direction ORDER BY aimed_arrival_time) AS arrival_order,
    time_recorded
FROM  
  `bigquery-public-data.san_francisco_transit_muni.stop_monitoring`
WHERE
  time_recorded >= '2020-01-01'
AND
  route_id NOT IN ('PH', 'PM', 'C')
AND
  (DATETIME_DIFF(time_recorded, aimed_arrival_time, SECOND)/60) >= -90 
AND
  (DATETIME_DIFF(time_recorded, aimed_arrival_time, SECOND)/60) <= 90)


SELECT
   route_id, 
    trip_id, 
    direction,
    trip_date, 
    stop_name,
    MIN(arrival_order),
    aimed_arrival_time,
    time_recorded
FROM
  ad
GROUP BY
  trip_id,
  trip_date,
  direction,
  route_id,
  stop_name,
  aimed_arrival_time,
  time_recorded
ORDER BY
  trip_id,
  direction,
  aimed_arrival_time,
  time_recorded
```

I'm getting duplicate rows - the DENSE RANK was there to help my identify multiple rows with the same data - is there a way to filter this out?

Comment: Can you provide the previous query in which your code works and your desired output.

Comment: whats considered a duplicate? provide outputs and highlight issues. from running your query i dont see any duplicates judging by aimed_arrival_times for example